# Issue when I join three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three tables `TeamTerritoryMapping`, `UpdQuotaTbl` and `tblInvoiceFile`

When I join the first two tables I am getting the correct result

```
 select 
     TTM.Team, Sum(Upd.Quota) as Quota 
 from 
     TeamTerritoryMapping TTM
 inner join 
     UpdQuotaTbl upd on upd.ITM = TTm.Territory
 where 
     upd.Month = 'july' 
 group by 
     TTM.Team
```

but when I join the third table for another column revenue from `tblinvoicefile`, some of the rows are getting duplicated and the end result is becoming higher. Below is the query which I am using to join 3 tables

```
select 
    TTM.Team,
    Sum(upd.Quota) as quota,
    sum(inv.[End MS Sales Revenue]) as Revenue 
from 
    UpdQuotaTbl Upd
inner join 
    TeamTerritoryMapping TTM on TTM.Territory = upd.ITM
inner join 
    tblInvoiceFile inv on inv.[Inv Territory] = TTM.Territory
where 
    upd.Month = 'july' 
    and inv.[End Fiscal Month] = 'July, 2013'
```

So how can I eradicate the duplicate values in third table, I am getting the correct value when I join two tables ie `TeamTerritoryMapping,UpdQuotaTbl` and also tables `TeamTerritoryMapping`.

Comment: Second query doesn't have `group by`.

Comment: It appears you have more than one quota for the same territory somewhere? Either that, or one invoice is mapping to more than one territory?  More than likely it's the duplicate Territory entries in TeamTerritoryMapping.

Comment: @Win If you're only getting a single SUM(), ie one number, you don't need a group by.  He might need an extra level of query with internal group by in this case, but it's a bit more complicated than just "add missing group by".

Comment: @ebyrob Huh, if you do `SELECT field, SUM(value) FROM table` then you most certainly need a `GROUP BY` on `field`. I know it would (kind of) work on e.g. mysql, but the result would be 'unpredictable'. AFAIK the syntax would fail on all versions of MSSQL.

Comment: @deroby I admit I have a heavy MySQL slant but the result of bare aggregate is hardly unpredictable.  (well field might be semi-random in a very few cases.  `GROUP BY 1` to fit the SQL standard certainly won't alleviate that).  Ah ok, he does drop the `GROUP BY` between the two queries, which is suspicious but hardly much to go on.

Comment: @user3417326: Do I understand this correctly; you want to show all TTMs that have at least one upd in July and at least one inv in July. For These you want to have the total quota for July and the total Revenue for July. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like tblInvoiceFile has multiple entires for [Invenio Territory] which is causing this issue.  If your intention is to bring in and sum all the [End MS Sales Revenue] for that table you can try something like this

```
SELECT TTM.Team,Sum(upd.Quota) as quota,sum(inv.[End MS Sales Revenue]) as Revenue 
FROM UpdQuotaTbl Upd
    INNER JOIN TeamTerritoryMapping TTM ON TTM.Territory = upd.ITM
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT [Invenio Territory], SUM([End MS Sales Revenue]) AS [End MS Sales Revenue]
            FROM  tblInvoiceFile 
            WHERE [End Fiscal Month] = 'July, 2013'
            GROUP BY [Invenio Territory]) AS inv 
        ON inv.[Invenio Territory] = TTM.Territory
WHERE upd.Month = 'july'
```

Comment: Shouldn't SUM(lots of records) in the end give the same result as SUM(SUM(unique records)) ?

Comment: My bad. The result would be identical for the `SUM` on the `[End MS Sales Revenue])` field from `tblInvoiceFile`, but it would mess up the one on `upd.Quote`. +1

Comment: I'm still not sure how you know **where** the duplication is.  Did I miss a fiddle or a result set somewhere?  (not to mention where you're getting column names not quite matching the original question...)

Comment: I tried using your code but the sub query is summing up the duplicates for revenue when you group by Invenio Territory.
which is giving the same result

Comment: if infact there are dups in tblInvoiceFile then you can simply do a MAX in the subquery instead of SUM.   I thought there was a one to many relationship between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

My initial response would be : The reason you're getting some results multiple times is because the `ON` used to join `tblInvoiceFile` is not 'unique' enough. If you look at the primary key (or a unique?) of said table you'll probably notice that it involves more than just the `Inv Territory` field.

To solve it you can do two different things.

1. Expand the `ON` clause to include more fields that make the connection unique
2. Keep the query as it is now but aggregate the results so the invoice information gets `SUM`med

The problem is, it seems like you're already `SUM()`-ing the information (although as noted by Win, you're missing the `GROUP BY`), so I'm not quite sure why this would not work.

UPDATE: Only now realise that your problem is not doubled records, but doubled values in the first SUM(). Best way to solve this is by PRE-aggregating the values as shown by Abhi.